# Properties of quotient variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Ok, so I have a projective variety $X$ over an algebraically closed field, and a finite group $G$ acting on $X$. Let $\pi:X\to Y=X/G$ be the quotient. Let $C$ be a curve in $Y$, and let $F=\pi^{-1}(C)$, given the reduced induced subscheme structure. My question has to do with the study of $F$, based on properties of $C$. For instance, if $C$ is nonsingular, can I tell when $F$ is nonsingular? It at least seems intuitive to me that if $C$ doesn't meet any singular points of $Y$, then $F$ should be nonsingular. Can I know what happens if $C$ does meet a singular point of $Y$?

EDIT: More specifically, let $X$ be an abelian variety, and let $-1:X\to X$ be multiplication by $-1$. The Kummer variety of $X$ is defined to be $\mbox{Km}(X):=X/\langle-1\rangle$. Now, multiplication by -1 is a nice automorphism that only creates problems around 2-torsion points. If I have a nonsingular curve $C$ in $\mbox{Km}(X)$, can I say anything about the singularities of $\pi^{-1}(C)$ ($\pi$ is the projection map)?

Comment: Consider the following example: $(x,y)\to (x^2,y)$. Then the preimage of the curve $x=y^2$ under this map is $x=\pm y$. It is singular at $(0,0)$. It seems to me that you need to make the question a bit more specific... 

Comment: You're right, question edited.

Comment: As Dmitri points out, it is not so much the singularities of Y as the branch locus of π that you have to worry about. Outside of that, π will be étale and therefore the inverse image of the part of C that lies outside of the branch locus will be non-singular. In the case where π:X→Y is the map from an abelian variety X to its quotient by -1, the non-étale locus is given by π(X[2]), which is a union of $2^{2 \operatorname{dim}(X)}$ points. Finding out what the inverse image of C looks like above any of the points in π(X[2]) should be a perfectly local problem.

Comment: Ok, I just didn't know if what I was analyzing was a part of the theory of quotients of varieties that had already been studied, or if there were general theorems about it, etc. This specific case is pretty easy to analyze, I was just wondering about possible generalizations. Thanks!